# Selenium write output to CSV using import csv and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, import-csv

I have a code which outputs all possible dropdown names (e.g color) , values (e.g red) and price per any given link. I want to write this output to a csv file under specific headings.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest\drivers\chromedriver.exe')
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import csv



from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import itertools
from pprint import pformat


def apply_values(dropdowns, values):
    """
    :param dropdowns: list of select DropDown
    :param values: list of values to set
    :return: dict with key=dropdownName, value=dropDownValue
    """
    r = {}
    for value in values:
        # For each value, get the associated DropDown and set it
        for dropdown in dropdowns:
            if value in dropdown.values:
                try:
                    dropdown.select_by_visible_text(value)
                    r[dropdown.name] = value
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    # print("Unable to set the following values {}..Skipping".format(values))
                    # This is caused by an option not being available with other selected dropdown values
                    # You can also check the attribute disabled for this
                    return False
                break
    return r

browser.get('https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Apple-iPhone-7-32GB-128GB-256GB-All-Colours-UNLOCKED-Various-Grades/133027295946?')
els = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".msku-sel")
selects = []
for el in els:
    # Adding the dropdown name to the select object
    name = el.get_attribute('name')
    select = Select(el)
    select.name = name
    selects.append(select)

print("Get all options for each dropdown")
for idx, sel in enumerate(selects):
    sel.values = [option.text for option in sel.options][1:]

print("Get all possible permutations")
permutations = list(itertools.product(*[sel.values for sel in selects]))

# Iteration for all possible permutation
print("Select all possible permutation and get price for each")
results = []
for permutation in permutations:
    # Resetting all parameter to default
    for sel in selects:
        sel.select_by_index(0)
    # Iteration to set each dropdown
    result = apply_values(selects, permutation)
    if result:
        # Once all dropdown value are set, get the finally price
        result['Price'] = browser.find_element_by_id("prcIsum").text
        results.append(result)

with open('results222.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("dropdown1Name,dropdown1Option,dropdown2Name,dropdown2Option,dropdown3Name,dropdown3Option,dropdown4Name,dropdown4Option,dropdown5Name,dropdown5Option,dropdown6Name,dropdown6Option \n")
    f.write(pformat(result))
    f.write(",  \n")
    f.write(result['Price'])
    f.write(",  \n")

print(pformat(results))


browser.close()
```

The current csv output is

```py
dropdown1Name,dropdown1Option,dropdown2Name,dropdown2Option,dropdown3Name,dropdown3Option,dropdown4Name,dropdown4Option,dropdown5Name,dropdown5Option,dropdown6Name,dropdown6Option 
{u'Color': u'Rose Gold',
 u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
 u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
 'Price': u'\xa3224.99',
 u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},  
£224.99,
```

First of all, i want this to be aligned e.g under dropdown1name title, i want color and so on. I dont want to use anyother format as i will be scraping many url and dropdown title will be different each time.

Also it is only writing the first set of scraping to the csv, despite the content output being

```py
[{u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade B - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3179.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A+ - Excellent',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3195.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3194.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade B - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3179.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'256GB [out of stock]'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A+ - Excellent',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3179.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'256GB [out of stock]'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3179.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'256GB [out of stock]'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade B - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3204.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A+ - Excellent',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3225.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Black',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3224.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade B - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3179.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A+ - Excellent',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3195.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3194.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade B - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3204.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A+ - Excellent',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3225.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3224.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Rose Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade B - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3179.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Rose Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A+ - Excellent',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3195.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Rose Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3194.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'32GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Rose Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade B - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3204.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Rose Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A+ - Excellent',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3225.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'},
 {u'Color': u'Rose Gold',
  u'Condition': u'Grade A - Very Good',
  u'Network': u'GSM Unlocked',
  'Price': u'\xa3224.99',
  u'Storage Capacity': u'128GB'}]
```

Help will be much appreciated following the format like this
    (e.g)            dropdown1name dropdown1option   etc
    url1(phone)     color         Black
    url2(tshirt)    size          small

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium write to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315954/selenium-write-to-csv)

Comment: not a duplicate